# Using bibtex files with coauthors

Tags: latex, mathematical-writing

When working with different coauthors, I have always had some troubles in using bibtex effectively. Everyone has its own set of bibtex entries, with keys in their own favorite format --- for instance, the same book could be indexed by different people as as `golubvanloan`, `GVL96`, `matrix_computations`, `GolubVanLoan`, `GolVL96`, `mc-book`...

I usually solve the problem by creating more or less a new `.bib` file for each paper, where each author copy-and-pastes entries from older files, and everyone keeps the keys he cites in their favorite format. Of course, this is not efficient. For every paper, a nontrivial amount of careful manual work is wasted adjusting the bibliography (e.g., pruning double entries).

What is your solution to this problem? Do you have shared `.bib` files, or common conventions across whole communities devoted to a single area of mathematics? Is there maybe any $\LaTeX$ command that lets you register double keys and refer to the same book with different keys? Is there a sensible method to avoid duplicate entries in the `.bib` files? Should Bibtex be dumped in favor of something better?

Comment: I voted to close.  There is now a StackExchange site for TeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See related question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/how-should-i-handle-bibtex-files-of-my-co-authors and also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/can-a-bibtex-entry-be-given-more-than-one-reference-name.

Comment: The problem has two sides --- a technical one and a "social" one (handling shared bibtex files, sticking to defined conventions).  And AFAIK there is no satisfying "technical" solution, as the tex.stackexchange questions that you have linked seem to confirm. Therefore I am afraid we need a "social" solution.

Moreover, the mathematical audience has more tools available (e.g., most articles have a unique MR code that can be used to index them) than the TeX community, so someone could use it for a better solution.

This is why I chose to post here rather than on tex.stackexchange.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, just one that I don't think it's appropriate to MO.  I'll vote to close, but let me leave a comment with how it works for me.  There's no reason not to use standard entries from MathSciNet (and in my own area also inSPIRE for the many preprints we cite).  I agree the keys are unmnemonic, but I use the RefTeX minor mode in Emacs and I don't ever need to input the key by hand.


Comment: Since this question now has 3 votes to close, and no one other than the author has spoken up in its favor, I think the time has come to close it.  I'm a little torn, but I agree with Jose that this is just not MO's purview.